# solr stopwords issue on UPPERCASE-query input

Tags: solr, filter, uppercase

)

I am using SolrStopFilter for some fields, to filter those words from incoming query. 
Here is the part of the schema for e.g. one field I am using:

```
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" dictionary="vkf_de_DE.dic" affix="vkf_de_DE.aff" ignoreCase="true" />
    </analyzer>
```

When I do a search for "korbstapelwagen MIT schiebebügel", I get no results. 
Using "korbstapelwagen mit schiebebügel" gives mit the exact 1 result!

The word "mit" exists in the stopwords.txt file (lowercased).

Analyzing that query in solr admin gives me:

```
 WT  - korbstapelwagen MIT schiebebügel
 LCF - korbstapelwagen mit schiebebügel
 SF  - korbstapelwagen     schiebebügel
 HSF - korbstapelwagen     schiebebügel
```

Why do I get no results when using the uppercased word "MIT" in my query? 
It is getting completely filtered by the StopWordFilter....

Comment: Is there any difference seen in the query using lower/upper case except for in the first step? What does the value say when the same value is present for indexing under analysis?

Comment: I dont use the StopFilter for indexing. You mean I should test the filter for indexing as well, to see whats happening?

Comment: Yes. What you have pasted seems like it should match, so it would be helpful to see what the analysis page says for both indexing and querying. Matches should have a slightly different background color on the analysis page.

Comment: I did this and got "korbstapelwagen" and "schiebebügel" with light blue background as a match